# What is the maximum size limit of varchar data type in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, size, varchar

I'm new to sqlite. I want to know the maximum size limit of varchar data type in sqlite?

can anybody suggest me some information related to this? I searched on sqlite.org site and they [give the answer as](http://www.sqlite.org/sessions/faq.html#q9):

> **Q.** What is the maximum size of a VARCHAR in SQLite?
>
> **A.** SQLite does not enforce the length of a VARCHAR. You can declare a VARCHAR(10) and SQLite will be happy to let you put 500
> characters in it. And it will keep all   500 characters intact - it
> never truncates.

but I want to know the exact max size limit of varchar datatype in sqlite.

Comment: You can read also this http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

Answer (score 50, accepted):

from http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

> Maximum length of a string or BLOB
>
> The maximum number of bytes in a
>   string or BLOB in SQLite is defined by
>   the preprocessor macro
>   SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH. **The default value of this macro is 1 billion** (1 thousand
>   million or 1,000,000,000). You can
>   raise or lower this value at
>   compile-time using a command-line
>   option like this:
>
> -DSQLITE_MAX_LENGTH=123456789 The current implementation will only
>   support a string or BLOB length up to
>   231-1 or 2147483647. And some built-in
>   functions such as hex() might fail
>   well before that point. In
>   security-sensitive applications it is
>   best not to try to increase the
>   maximum string and blob length. In
>   fact, you might do well to lower the
>   maximum string and blob length to
>   something more in the range of a few
>   million if that is possible.
>
> During part of SQLite's INSERT and
>   SELECT processing, the complete
>   content of each row in the database is
>   encoded as a single BLOB. So the
>   SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH parameter also
>   determines the maximum number of bytes
>   in a row.

Comment: For reference: assuming 1-byte characters, this is slightly less than a GB. (Or exactly one GB, if base 10 is how you measure bits)

Comment: How many characters could be stored in 1 byte in SQLite, exactly?

Comment: @renatov I don't think you can measure in characters, it depends on the encoding you use for the database https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html and the character that is being entered. UTF-8 for example can have between 1 and 4 bytes per character, whether ASCII only uses 1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290182/how-many-bytes-does-one-unicode-character-take

Comment: @renatov Oh, just to make it clear that I said ASCII as an example, as it seems not to be supported by sqlite https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: @renatov here is a very nice video showing how utf-8 and string encoding works :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MijmeoH9LT4