# Is it efficient to store the entire text of a blog post in the text field of an SQL database?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Say I want to store a blog post (or another long text) in a `text` field of an SQLite3 database under python. Is this the most efficient method? would it be better to store it as a text file on my hard drive?

Comment: Put it in the DB.  Unless you're regularly storing posts of similar length to *War and Peace* there's really no need to create all the headaches you'll get from adding the filesystem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting the blog text in the database is perfectly fine and a `TEXT` column type is appropriate for that.

In fact, a `TEXT` column can handle up to a [billion characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6214844/1980659). So unless you have very long blog entry you will be fine.  Moreover it will be much more simple than messing with writing/reading files.