# can't figure out URIException

Tags: java, spring, uri, jersey-client

I receive the following error:

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: "http://localhost:8080/MyService"
```

Is there really something wrong with my 'h' character? Or is there maybe some hidden character I'm not seeing?

I am loading that string in from a property file, so I even made sure I called trim() before using it to construct the URI.

This is the code where it is occuring. the value of `uri` is that of the string in the exception printout. Client is that of the jersey framework

```
    final Client CLIENT = Client.create();
    final WebResource webResource = CLIENT.resource(uri);
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: Can you try to read the bytes from the properties directly and check if there is something before the `h` in the string you are holding it in?

Comment: added the client code. I will look into that @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: can you post what is going on inside CLIENT.resource method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not the h, but that the first character in your string is a quotation mark (").

Comment: this was the issue. Pretty embarassing considering I explicitly looked for that, but my brain farted I guess. This combined with @SotiriosDelimanolis suggestion helped me identify the first byte being a quote. Thanks, will accept in 5 min

Comment: @75inchpianist Just fyi, it's not actually just 1 byte, should've reworded.

Comment: what do you mean? I thought each char took up a byte

Comment: @75inchpianist http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290182/how-many-bytes-takes-one-unicode-character Different encoding, different length.

Comment: application.properties had value url="https://135.250.138.145:28443", removing " worked for me

Answer (score 4):

I believe (if I recall properly) that that particular error message should not quote the URI, thus the URI must have been quoted to start with.....