# How write string of bits in binary file in python 3?

Tags: file, python-3.x, file-io, binary

i have a string of bytes like temp="101110110011"
i want to write this string in binary file.
i did it by :

```
with open("some binary file.bin", "wb") as f:
    bytes = str.encode (some string)
    f.write(bytes)
```

but because I use it for huffman encoding it will make my bin file size larger

how to save above string as binary directly  in python 3 
my string range is more than 32 bits

Comment: What problem are you seeking help with exactly?

Comment: Do you expect `"10111011"` to occupy 1 byte or 8 in the file?

Comment: `"101110110011"` looks suspiciously like a string of *bits*, not *bytes*. Are missing a conversion step?

Comment: yes I have string of bits. now how I write this string in binary file.

Comment: from array import *

`bin_array = array('B')

bin_array.append(int('011',2))
bin_array.append(int('010',2))
bin_array.append(int('110',2))

f = file('binary.mydata','wb')
bin_array.tofile(f)
f.close()`

Comment: i found above code from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887493/write-a-binary-integer-or-string-to-a-file-in-python)

Comment: but does not work on python 3.x

Comment: yes I have string of bits. now how I write this string in binary file?@MisterMiyagi

Comment: yes I have string of bits. now how I write this string in binary file?@JonClements