# UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: ordinal not in range(256)

Tags: python

everyone!
I use python3(pycharm),and my codes are like these:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy

c=numpy.loadtxt('test.csv',dtype="str_",delimiter=',',usecols=(6,),unpack=True)
```

when I have some Chinese words in test.csv,I got a error like this:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: ordinal not in range(256)
```

I have tried to encode the file,like this:

```
c=numpy.loadtxt('test.csv'.encode('utf-8'),dtype="str_",skiprows=0,delimiter=',',usecols=(6,),unpack=True)
```

And then,I got another error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Besides,the Chinese words in the file are longer than 64.

I have waste a lot of time on this,Please give me a hand！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we read the Chinese character to numpy, the data type cannot be a simple string because it treats the character as ASCII which is not long enough to hold the UTF-8 character.

So what I have done here is to let numpy knows we are reading a 4-byte character instead which is sufficient to hold an unicode character.

I have used the following sample data for testing:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
一,二,三,四,五,六,七
```

Here is the code I have used:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy
c=numpy.genfromtxt('test.csv',dtype="S4",delimiter=',',usecols=(6,),unpack=True)

for txt in c:
    print(txt.decode("utf-8"))
```

You can further check the below links to learn more:
1. [How many bytes does one Unicode character take?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290182/how-many-bytes-does-one-unicode-character-take)
2. [Numpy Data type objects](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)

Comment: In my csv,it can read 7,but can't read 七.And it comes out an error:`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 0: invalid continuation byte`

Comment: Hi Robin, would you share your testing csv file content?

Comment: By the way, have you saved your testing CSV in utf-8 format?

Comment: @ Simon MC.Cheng.Hello,My csv's format is GB2312.So when I changed `print(txt.decode('utf-8')` to `print(txt.decode('GB2312')`,it works well!Thank you very much.And if I want to read a much longer string,I can change the dtype,am I right?

Comment: @Robin, yes, you can change the value of dtype to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('test.csv', encoding='utf-8') as fh:
    numpy.loadtxt(fh, dtype="str_", delimiter=',', usecols=(6,), unpack=True)
```

Comment: Now there's a new error:'UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 0: invalid continuation byte'