# Why is the size of a character 2 bytes in java?

Tags: java

In all the low-level languages the size a of char is 1 byte. So why does char have a size of 2 bytes in Java?

Comment: Because with Unicode it's possible to encode practically every single character (that exists in every language)

Comment: The size of a character depends on the encoding format that you use. Some formats use even more than 2 bytes. If you use only 1 byte, you are practically limited to the old ASCII. Newer schemes support more characters, and more importantly more languages.

Comment: C++ has several character datatypes and only one of them is defined as "at least 8 bits". Your assertion is simply incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 'char' type represents an UNICODE character which is two bytes long

Comment: Well, *was* 2 bytes long. Then they realized it's not enough and it got [even more complicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290182/how-many-bytes-does-one-unicode-character-take).

Comment: Yes you are right about UNICODE characters, but to preserve the compatibility of Java program the 'char' data type will remain 16 bits long. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

char is a data structure that is 16 bits. Thus 2 bytes (8-bits each) is 16 bits.

Comment: Yes, but the question wants to know why. In other languages, characters are 1-byte long (well... usually; that's probably changing as unicode is gaining ground on ascii). See Luci's answer.

Comment: `char` is a primitive that is _always_ 16 bits long in Java, just like `int` is _always_ 32 bits long. Not "by default" because there's no other option. Furthermore, `char` is a numeric primitive, and is a "data structure" in the same way that `int` is.

Comment: I corrected the use of the English language to appease you. But, I stand by the fact that char is a data structure, much like int is as well.