# StreamReader does not read the last character

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, character-encoding

MyFile.txt contains (in Hex):

**40 D8 40**

I print all of its characters by:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("MyFile.txt"))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
         int n = sr.Read();
         Console.WriteLine("{0:X}", n);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
40
FFFD
40
```

**But**, when MyFile.txt contains the same chars while **D8** is the last one:

**40 40 D8**

The output is only:

```
40
40
```

Where is the last char **D8** (FFFD)??

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out.  The Encoding that it uses needs to match the file content, you are not providing properly encoded utf8.  If you are only interesting in the binary content then you need to use FileStream.

Comment: What is the encoding of your file?

Comment: add this line to check for nulls prior inside your while loop 
`if ((n= sr.ReadLine()) != null)`

Comment: @dlatikay I took it from Hex Editor

Comment: @STLDeveloper It's never mind, this is the content from hex-editor...

Comment: @dlatikay 0xD8 is _nothing_ in ASCII. ASCII is 7-bit and only goes up to 0x7F.

Comment: right. my answer made this stale comment obsolete, I deleted it

Answer (score 0):

`StreamReader` is expecting the input to be utf8. Unless you specify a different encoding, or use a binary `FileStream` instead, you will get invalid code points represented as 0xFF sequences in the output.

In your actual case, 0xD8 is a valid Unicode prefix aka "plane selector", but 0x40 is not a valid continuation byte to form a codepoint with: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/d840/index.htm

> U+D840 is not a valid unicode character.

[Related, interesting read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33349765/1132334) - in your second situation, the last char is missing because a prefix alone does not resolve into a character. The framework expects a continuation byte to determine a valid codepoint, but encounters end-of-stream and outputs nothing.